# Camera Rotation in Direct X 11

Tags: camera, rotation, directx-11

I can't seem to get my camera to rotate based on its own local axis. It will only rotate about the origin on both the X and Y rotations.

```
POINT cursorPos;
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
LONG deltaX = oldCursorPos.x - cursorPos.x;
LONG deltaY = oldCursorPos.y - cursorPos.y;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))
{
    XMMATRIX xRotation = XMMatrixRotationY((-deltaX * (float)timer.Delta()));
    XMMATRIX yRotation = XMMatrixRotationX((-deltaY * (float)timer.Delta()));

    XMFLOAT4 viewVector = XMFLOAT4(sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][0], sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][1], sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][2], sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][3]);
    XMVECTOR pos = XMLoadFloat4(&viewVector);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) { sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][i] = 0.0f; }
    XMMATRIX view = XMLoadFloat4x4(&sceneMatrix.viewMatrix);

    view = xRotation * view;
    view = view * yRotation;

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&sceneMatrix.viewMatrix, view);

    sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][0] = XMVectorGetX(pos);
    sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][1] = XMVectorGetY(pos);
    sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][2] = XMVectorGetZ(pos);
    sceneMatrix.viewMatrix.m[3][3] = XMVectorGetW(pos);
}

oldCursorPos = cursorPos;
```

At first I thought I was multiplying them in the wrong order, but when I reverse them I **still** rotate around the origin. I can't pick out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Given all the mixing of scalar and vector operations here, you'd be better off making use of the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local rotational axes that you need are built into the view matrix... kind of. A view matrix is an inverted form of a matrix that represents the camera's worldspace location and rotation. First you must invert the view matrix, then the camera's local x axis is row one, the y axis is row 2, and the z axis is row 3. (or you can out smart the inversion process by using the appropriate columns to extract the local vectors). then, instead of using `XMMatrixRotationX`, use an axis/angle version where you can plug in those local axis: `XMMatrixRotationAxis` or `XMMatrixRotationNormal` for the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply how Rotation Matrices work. They rotate every point in space around the origin.

[image: RotationMatrix]
<sub>(source: [sharetechnote.com](http://www.sharetechnote.com/image/EngMath_Matrix_Affin_Rotate.PNG))</sub>

To rotate your camera around the y-axis for example you'd set x = 0 & z = 0. You then apply the rotation matrix (now it's looking to a different location) and then move the camera back to it's original position.

Another option would be to create a view matrix to simulate the whole camera for you and change it every frame or so.

Comment: But his original code does that. His code snippet records his view position, sets it to zero, rotates his view matrix, then resets the view's position back to the original position just like your answer suggests. Why are you suggesting he solve his problem by doing what he is already doing?

Comment: I know how matrices work in 3D space, the issue was that I wasn't getting the expected result even while following the formula for a **local** camera rotation. I realized that I wasn't performing the inverse operation correctly and that was causing the false rotation. I was attempting to use only the view matrix but my solution was to create a camera matrix as well that handled the rotations and translations, and setting the view matrix equal to the inverse of the camera matrix every frame. Thank you both!